# Heroku compilation failure. Illigal character

Tags: maven, heroku, spring-boot

It is my first time trying to submit any app to the heroku. I was following  [this tutorial.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku) 
I have an installed Spring CLI. I commited changes to git and use command **heroku create**, which work out fine but when use: **git push heroku master** i am getting an error during the compilation which goes like this:

> [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
>   [ERROR]/tmp/build_c2569e1c27c1c307e42528c66e67c016/src/main/java/com/example/configuration/SecurityConfig.java:[123,125]
>   illegal start of expression
>   [ERROR]/tmp/build_c2569e1c27c1c307e42528c66e67c016/src/main/java/com/example/configuration/SecurityConfig.java:[123,126]
>   ';' expected [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project demo: Compilation failure: Compilation
>   failure:
>   [ERROR]/tmp/build_c2569e1c27c1c307e42528c66e67c016/src/main/java/com/example/configuration/SecurityConfig.java:[123,125]
>   illegal start of expression
>          [ERROR]/tmp/build_c2569e1c27c1c307e42528c66e67c016/src/main/java/com/example/configuration/SecurityConfig.java:[123,126]
>   ';' expected

Project compiles and starts perfectly fine on local machine, does anyone have ideas what may be wrong?

Here is the SecuityConfig calss

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String HMAC_ALGO = "HmacSHA256";

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myUserDetailService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.httpBasic();
        http.addFilterAfter(new CsrfTokenToCookieFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
        http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());
        http.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/admin/**").hasRole(Authorities.SUPER_ADMIN_VAL)
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/admin").hasAnyRole(Authorities.ROLE_ADMIN_VAL, Authorities.SUPER_ADMIN_VAL)
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/admin").hasRole(Authorities.SUPER_ADMIN_VAL)
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/admin").hasRole(Authorities.SUPER_ADMIN_VAL)
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/admin").hasRole(Authorities.SUPER_ADMIN_VAL)
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/order", "/client").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/").hasRole(Authorities.ROLE_ADMIN_VAL)
                .regexMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/").hasRole(Authorities.ROLE_ADMIN_VAL)
                .regexMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/").hasRole(Authorities.ROLE_ADMIN_VAL)
                .regexMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/").hasRole(Authorities.ROLE_ADMIN_VAL)
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/").permitAll();
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }
}
```

The weirdest part is that error points into 123-d line when the actual class contains only 66 lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was, that i have totally forgot to make a pull request to the master brunch. Don`t have did i manged to commit code with an error to the master brunch in the first place. Now everything fixed and working.